# sql - join 2 tables 10 times

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have 2 tables structured like this:

```
People
----------
>ID, Name, Surname

Projects
----------
>ID, Assistant#1,  Assistant#2,  Assistant#3,  Assistant#4, 
> Assistant#5,  Assistant#6,  Assistant#7,  Assistant#8,  Assistant#9, 
> Assistant#10, lot of other columns..... (every assistant column
> contains an integer, the people ID)
```

Now, I want to query my DB and get a single row from Project table (let's suppose row with ID=3) containing all columns of project table and in particular have each assistant replaced with it's correct name and surname.
I've managed to do this (with a lot of joins), but with my little sql experience my code looks very bulky and i'm sure that there's a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear, edit it first and clearify it with sample data and desired result

Comment: I styled my tables like this because auctually there aren't 10 columns with the same name, but every one has it's own. However, should I really restyle my tables and add another one like many users said? What are the benefit of this? Honestly I can't understand why...because I'm unexperienced :)

Comment: @Stefano - So the benefit to having a more relational table structure (in a Relational Database) would be that: 1) You only need to store what information is there (if there is only one assistant then you only have one row, rather than 10 columns). 2) Your join(s) don't have to be as complicated, in my post the first two queries are for your table structure, but my last query will work for the proposed structure (much more straightforward and much easier to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set a number of (possible) assistants at 10, that dictates that you are going to have to write code to accomodate those 10 assistants. This can be done a few ways: (have not tested)

```
select * from projects proj
left join people p1 on proj.assistant1 = p1.peopleid
left join people p2 on proj.assistant2 = p2.peopleid
left join people p3 on proj.assistant3 = p3.peopleid
left join people p4 on proj.assistant4 = p4.peopleid
left join people p5 on proj.assistant5 = p5.peopleid
left join people p6 on proj.assistant6 = p6.peopleid
left join people p7 on proj.assistant7 = p7.peopleid
left join people p8 on proj.assistant8 = p8.peopleid
left join people p9 on proj.assistant9 = p9.peopleid
left join people p10 on proj.assistant10 = p10.peopleid
```

otherwise you could do some trickery with

```
select proj.projectID, 
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant1),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant2),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant3),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant4),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant5),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant6),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant7),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant8),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant9),
(select * from people where peopleID = proj.assistant10)
from projects proj
```

If possible, it might be best to re-structure your datatables, and have a single assistant mapped to a single projectID:

```
PeopleID, Name, Surname

ProjectID, PeopleID
```

Therefore, you could do just one inner join and you will return a row for each assistant:

```
select * from projects proj 
inner join people p 
on p.peopleID = proj.peopleid
where proj.projectID = PROJECTID
```

Comment: -1 the first query will never work as intended since the moment there's a null value in a column the row won't be returned. The subselect in the second option is very inefficient.

Comment: I think icarus is correct. Won't a query based on multiple inner joins fail if any one of them fails to find any records? I'd think you'd want to use left outer joins so that you'd get NULL in the fields where a match wasn't found, while still returning valid values in fields where a match was found. I also agree with the other posters who have mentioned that this is a clunky and generally risky approach, and normalizing by using a project assistants table would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about the inner vs. left joins. you're absolutely correct. I did mention that if restructuring was possible, that would be beneficial. Unfortunately I do understand that sometimes that is not a possibility so I wanted to give another option besides the "lots of joins" mentioned in the question (hence option 2)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Surname
FROM People p
CROSS JOIN Project j ON (p.PeopleID = j.Assistant1 OR
p.PeopleID = j.Assistant2 OR
p.PeopleID = j.Assistant3 OR
.. etc)
AND j.ProjectID = 3
```

Your performance will be awful, but that's the price you pay for having a horribly designed database. The better solution is to map a project and people by the means of a decomposition:

```
CREATE TABLE proj_people
People_ID INT
Project_ID INT
```

Answer (score 4):

Your structure is not clear to me. I advice you to create a clutch for projects.

Tables:

`Peoples`
people_id, people_name, people_surname

`Projects`
project_id, project_name

`Clutch`
project_id, people_id

Comment: +1 That's the standard way to represent a many-to-many relationship. Though I'd name the new table ProjectPeople, to reflect which other tables it relates to. Clutch is pretty ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested :)

```
Select * from project pr
left join people pe1 on pe1.peopleid = pr.astint1
left join people pe2 on pe2.peopleid = pr.astint2
left join people pe3 on pe3.peopleid = pr.astint3
left join people pe4 on pe4.peopleid = pr.astint4
left join people pe5 on pe5.peopleid = pr.astint5 
left join people pe6 on pe6.peopleid = pr.astint6
left join people pe7 on pe7.peopleid = pr.astint7
left join people pe8 on pe8.peopleid = pr.astint8
left join people pe9 on pe9.peopleid = pr.astint9
left join people pe10 on pe10.peopleid = pr.astint10
where pr.projectid = 3
```

Comment: only significant adjustment I would have here is LEFT join.  What if a record only has 3 assistants... This would not include such records that had any SINGLE (or more) assistants NOT filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cleaner design is:

People table:

```
People ID, Name, Surname
```

ProjectAssistants table:

```
Project ID, Assistant Person ID
```

Projects table:

```
Project ID, lots of other columns (but no Assistant columns)
```

Then, the SQL becomes something like:

```
SELECT pr.*, p.* 
FROM Projects pr 
JOIN ProjectAssistants p_a ON pr.ProjectID = p_a ProjectID 
JOIN People p ON p_a.AssistantPersonID = p.PeopleID 
WHERE ProjectID = X
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to solve a data presentation issue at the database level and this is rarely a good idea. You should have a table holding projectid and assistantid only, having the combination of both columns as the primary key of the table. This will allow you to join this table to the assistant table and the project table only once and get all the results you need. This will also have the benefit of allowing you to support many more assistants on a project in the future without having to alter your queries to add yet more joins.

In conclusion you should have 3 tables:

```
Project
Assistant
ProjectAssistant (projectid,assistantid)
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to restructure your tables. I hate seeing tables with multiple columns for essentially the same thing multiple times. If you restructure to have 3 tables:

Person

```
PeopleID | Name | Surname
```

Project

```
ProjectID | ...other columns except Assistant
```

Project_Person

```
ProjectID | PersonID
```

That way you can assign multiple assistants to the same project without the need for multiple Assistant columns. Then you could use something like this to get the required results:

```
SELECT proj.ProjectID, pers.Name, pers.Surname
FROM Person pers
INNER JOIN Project_Person pp ON pp.PersonID = pers.PersonID
INNER JOIN Project proj ON proj.ProjectID = pp.ProjectID
```

This will not return a single row, but that is not how SQL is designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to/can't change the table structure then maybe use a user defined function?

`CREATE FUNCTION GET_ASS_NAME (n1 ASS_NO)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
   DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
     DECLARE fullname VARCHAR(50);
    SELECT fullname = CONCAT(NAME, ' ', SURNAME) FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID = n1;
     RETURN fullname;
    END|`

then

`select GET_ASS_NAME(1), GET_ASS_NAME(2), GET_ASS_NAME(3), ...
from    PROJECTS
where   ID = 3`